# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 23760 into shape (240,1,28,28)

Tags: python, pandas, image-processing, reshape

```
# Reshape and normalize training data
trainX = train[:, 1:].reshape(train.shape[0],1,28, 28).astype( 'float32' )
x_train = trainX / 255.0

y_train = train[:,98]

# Reshape and normalize test data
testX = test[:,1:].reshape(test.shape[0],1, 28, 28).astype( 'float32' )
x_test = testX / 255.0

y_test = test[:,98]
```

I try to reshape my csv train_data and test_data into 3-D Matrix but I get an error:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-57-268af51a6b14> in <module>()
----> 1 trainX = train[:, 1:].reshape(train.shape[0],1,28, 28).astype( 'float32' )
      2 x_train = trainX / 255.0
      3
      4 y_train = train[:,98]
      5
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 23760 into shape (240,1,28,28)
```

[Error Report Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJotn.png)

Comment: Please copy-paste the error text into your question, images are not accessible to everyone and are not searchable.

Comment: `    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
      <ipython-input-57-268af51a6b14> in <module>()
      ----> 1 trainX = train[:, 1:].reshape(train.shape[0],1,28, 28).astype( 'float32' )
      2 x_train = trainX / 255.0
      3 
      4 y_train = train[:,98]
      5 

      ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 23760 into shape (240,1,28,28)`

Comment: Ok, I’ve edited it into your question for you. Please note that you can [edit] your question at any time to improve it.

Comment: Also, what is surprising about the error message? You want to create a 240x1x28x28 array, which has 188160 elements, using only 23760 elements. You will need a lot more data for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, 23760 != 240*1*28*28, so reshaping into that particular array is impossible. In fact, 28*28 doesn't even divide 23760, so even if `train.shape[0]` were replaced with something else, this would never work.

Assuming that `train.shape[0]` and `1` are what you want to use for the first two dimensions, the final dimensions need to have a product of 23760/240 = 99. As this isn't a square number, the two numbers will have to differ. The prime factorization of 99 is 99 = 3*3*11, so the only possible options are

```
(240, 1, 1, 99), (240, 1, 3, 33), (240, 1, 9, 11),
```

and their permutations.